# Integration of Drools (Expert System) with Android Projects

Tags: android, integration, drools

I'm interested in developing an Android App using the Drools (JBoss) expert systems rules based system. It's got a plugin via Eclipse per their tools (v3.2) but I don't exactly know how to integrate Drools Jars into and Android project successfully. There has some talk about the issue (see below) but I don't know if it's been completely resolved. Can anyone enlighten me.

http://blogs.siliconindia.com/vinayGuntaka/Intergrating_External_Jars_ie_Drools_Jars__to_Android_and_Developing_Android_Programs-bid-HshzM96A62906557.html

http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Beginners/2010-01/msg00318.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, do you know how to create android projects? and how to add external jars to your android projects? When you reach that stage, this post may help. It talks about jbpm5 running in android but it depends on drools so it should be the same.
http://kverlaen.blogspot.com/2011/03/jbpm5-lightweight-running-on-android.html
Cheers

Comment: I've published an android App prior to this, as well as gotten Prolog to run on Android in as a java app. I got Drools to the point of compilation but not with the rules since the rules have to be compiled first before deploying and that conflicts with the native Android compiling process. My hopes now hinge on the V6 release of Drools that includes the lazy Rete which hopefully is less memory intensive, and is geared toward the mobile platform.

Answer (score 3):

here is another working option, I made a little modification on drools libaries for loading and running DRL rules on android.

check it, hope be helpful:

https://github.com/jorgemfk/dr-drools-android-demo

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mx.dr.drools

[image: drools running on android]

Answer (score 2):

I forked Drools 6 and modified it to use Dex for class generation and it works on Android (*using serialized packages compiled on desktop*)  I put an [Android application sample on github](http://www.github.com/kedzie/drools-android-sample)

Comment: Awesome! I'll check it out. Can I get back to you with questions?