# Drools - Error creating field accessor for TypeDeclaration

Tags: java, android, drools

I created a simple project using Drools and Java basing on [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/drools/drools_sample_drools_program.htm). It worked perfectly, so I adapted it to what I wanted to do. My DRL files use mvel dialect (instead of Java dialect) and initializing takes place in rule "initial" inside DRL file. You can see this project (source code as well as libraries and DRL file) [here](https://bitbucket.org/pm_rulesengines/drools_desktop/src). My DRL file looks more less like the following:

```css
package omd
dialect "mvel"
declare ocenaKwalifikacji
    value : Double
end
declare ocenaKandydata
    value : Double
end
declare ocenaTestow
    value : Double
end
declare ocenaRozmowy
    value : Double
end

rule "ocenakandydata/1 "
when
$ocenaRozmowy : ocenaRozmowy(value==5.0000)
$ocenaKwalifikacji : ocenaKwalifikacji(value==5.0000)
$ocenaTestow : ocenaTestow(value==5.0000)
then
  insert(new ocenaKandydata (5.0000))
  System.out.println("ocenaKandydata setting to 5.0000)");
end
rule "ocenakandydata/2 "
when
$ocenaRozmowy : ocenaRozmowy(value==5.0000)
$ocenaKwalifikacji : ocenaKwalifikacji(value==4.0000)
$ocenaTestow : ocenaTestow(value==5.0000)
then
  insert(new ocenaKandydata (5.0000))
  System.out.println("ocenaKandydata setting to 5.0000)");
end

...

rule "ocenakandydata/64 "
when
$ocenaRozmowy : ocenaRozmowy(value==2.0000)
$ocenaKwalifikacji : ocenaKwalifikacji(value==2.0000)
$ocenaTestow : ocenaTestow(value==2.0000)
then
  insert(new ocenaKandydata (2.0000))
  System.out.println("ocenaKandydata setting to 2.0000)");
end

rule "initial"
when
then
/*DATA*/
insert(new ocenaKwalifikacji(5.0));
    insert(new ocenaRozmowy(2.0));
    insert(new ocenaTestow(2.0));
end
```

Everything works fine, but the package in the first line must be `omd` although all classes are in the `com.sample` package. When I changed the package name to `com.sample`, I got the following error:

```
Error creating field accessors for TypeDeclaration 'ocenaKandydata' for type 'ocenaKandydata'.
```

**And now there is all the fun...**

I created similar project for Android. I used the same code, but the libraries come from [another example](https://github.com/jorgemfk/dr-drools-android-demo) (the previous ones did put classes in java.* or javax.* packages, which is not allowed while programming for Android). You can see this project [here](https://bitbucket.org/pm_rulesengines/drools_android). I put the `psc-zatrudnienie-ocena_kandydata.drl` file in the smartphone storage under `/storage/emulated/0/drools/psc-zatrudnienie-ocena_kandydata.drl`. When the package in the DRL file is `pl.me.drools2tp` (the same as all classes in Android app are placed in), I get following errors (similar to those ones above):

```css
Error creating field accessors for TypeDeclaration 'ocenaKwalifikacji' for type 'ocenaKwalifikacji'
Error creating field accessors for TypeDeclaration 'ocenaKandydata' for type 'ocenaKandydata'
Error creating field accessors for TypeDeclaration 'ocenaTestow' for type 'ocenaTestow'
Error creating field accessors for TypeDeclaration 'ocenaRozmowy' for type 'ocenaRozmowy'
```

and when I change the package name in DRL file to something another, the errors are as following:

```css
Class 'ocenaKwalifikacji' not found for type declaration of 'ocenaKwalifikacji'
Class 'ocenaKandydata' not found for type declaration of 'ocenaKandydata'
Class 'ocenaTestow' not found for type declaration of 'ocenaTestow'
Class 'ocenaRozmowy' not found for type declaration of 'ocenaRozmowy'
```

Could anybody give me some advice about this? What does exactly "field accessor for TypeDeclaration" mean? All the classes which are mentioned in `declare` part of the DRL file are also defined in Java, have `value` field and both getters and setters. The dekstop version uses Drools 5.3.0 (there is a huge sort of JAR files from http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/ as it was said on TutorialsPoint site). There is also one question connected with mine: [Integration of Drools (Expert System) with Android Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646934/integration-of-drools-expert-system-with-android-projects)

I will be very grateful for some help, tips or examples.

Best regards,
Peter.

BTW I use IntelliJ and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Do not compile with Java classes in com.sample and a DRL file in the same package with declare statements contradicting the Java classes.

From your question I assume that you have the same duplication of a class being declared in DRL in contrast or addition to some Java code.

Simply omit all the declare statements and stick with the Java classes *or* keep the declares and move the Java classes into another package.

BTW: make your class fields private.

Comment: So, the matter looks as follows:

Comment: 1. the package in DRL file is pl.me.drools2tp and the 'ocenaXXX' classes are in package pl.me.drools2tp; there are `declare` definitions in DRL file as well. Then I get **Error creating field accessor ... **

2. When I move 'ocenaXXX' classes to `pl.me.drools2tp.model` package, I get this: ` Class 'ocenaXXX' not found for type declaration of 'ocenaXXX'
[DialectError message='Unable to wire compiled classes, probably related to compilation failures:Unable to wire up JavaDialect']`

Comment: 3. When I put `ocenaXXX` classes in `pl.me.drools2tp` package, and remove `declare` statements from DRL file (with `pl.me.drools2tp` package in the first line),  I get this:
`Unable to build constraint as  'value' is invalid : [Rule name='ocenaKandydata/1 ']` (the error occurs 3 times for each rule)

Comment: Add to that, I also get such errors (when case 3 occurs):
java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullorg.drools.base.pl.me.drools2tp.ocenaRozmowy149761830$getValue.apk: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) (simiar errors are for `ocenaTestow` and `ocenaKwalifikacji` - not for `ocenaKandydata`).

They all are caused by Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: I have just updated my repo:
https://bitbucket.org/pm_rulesengines/drools_android

Comment: If you remove the declare statements, your rules have to reference the fields of the Java classes, where, IIRC, there is no field "value" - hence the error.

Comment: I suggest that you get your rules working in a standard Java environment and move to Android only after you have learned to handle that.

Comment: When you look at these Java classes, you can notice that they have a field called "value". Apart from that, the desktop version runs when I remove these classes and keep `declare` statements.

Comment: But there wasn't when I looked at those classes three days ago. - It's not possible to use this SO Q&A format as the backbone for  continuing discussions, especially when you don't put all the relevant code into the question.